# Owin OpenIDConnect challenge with ASP.NET WebAPI2

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, owin, openid-connect, adal

I found a [template](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant) to connect Office365 services through AzureAD for a MultiTenant web app.

That is great but this sample is written in ASP.NET MVC and I would like to modify it and make it work as an Angular SPA with ASP.NET WebAPI2.

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = SettingsHelper.ClientId,
        Authority = SettingsHelper.Authority,

        TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false
        },

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
            {
                var code = context.Code;
                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.AppKey);
                string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                string signInUserId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("{0}/{1}", SettingsHelper.AuthorizationUri, tenantID), new ADALTokenCache(signInUserId));he
                AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, SettingsHelper.AADGraphResourceId);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },

            RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
            {
                string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },

            AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

}

The *SignIn* method in *AccountController* is invoked via an ASP.NET MVC *Action.Link*

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public void SignIn()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
}
```

The *AccountController* is an MVC controller and the method *.Challenge* of the *IAuthenticationManager* actually makes a 302 redirection to the authority url with the appropriate OAuth2 url parameters. If we reuse the same code in an *ApiController* and call it via *XHR* it does not work it returns the OpenId cookie to the client and obviously does not redirect.

What would be a valid *SignIn* method for an *ApiController*?

Comment: Hi @Benoit, did you get any solution to this? Or we are trying altogether a wrong approach?

Comment: @openandfree Microsoft provided a sample using MVC: https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet. This MVC solution redirects to Microsoft successfully but the WebAPI one doesn't.